# Is there a way in CSS to stop video in going full screen when phone is rotated?

Tags: html, jquery, css, iframe, fullscreen

I embedded a video using iframe and it's working fine in portrait mode on my iPhone. I can scroll and listen to the video while reading the rest of the page.

But whenever I rotate my phone, it enters full screen and I can't scroll down anymore. It just focuses on the video. I want the same function it's doing in portrait mode but I'm stuck.

I tried media query but it's still not working

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    iframe {
    allowfullscreen: false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a little runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem - it makes it easier to test on an actual phone. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
<video controls webkit-playsinline playsinline>
    <source src="file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Try using **webkit-playsinline** and **playsinline**.
It should make it play where it is instead of the defaulf.

Hope it helps.